# asp mvc-5 client side requried validation for List dosn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

i've a view model with list attribule

```
 [Required]
 public List<Surgeons> Surgeons { get; set; }
```

the validation works fine on the server side, but it didn't work on the client side. I want to use the required validation not a custom one

Comment: You cant. jQuery validation works on form controls and you do not (and cannot) create a form control for `Surgeons` (only for each property of `Surgeons`). And it does not work on the server either (an empty `List<Surgeons>` with no items would pass validation).

Comment: it worked on the server as i creating the controls of the list using js. I agree with the reason why it dosn't work on the client side

Comment: It **does not** work on the server. A `RequiredAttribute` means the value of not `null` (it does not validate that is at least one item in the collection)

Comment: the value passed with null ... i create a list of hidden fields dynamically on the js , so if there is no hidden fields passed the value will be null

Comment: Your not understanding what I am saying. A `RequiredAttribute` does NOT work on a collection of complex properties - an empty list with no items be valid (and if you were to add a default constructor in you model with `Surgeons = new List<Surgeons>()` you would see that). Do NOT rely on a `RequiredAttribute`

Comment: i understand that but that wasn't my case.  if i used a custom validation i think it won't solve the client side problem I just wanted to keep the view model clean :( . thanks Stephen :)

Comment: on submit the model is passed with null

Comment: Its simply not possible. Handle the forms `.submit()` event, and write you own javascript code to do you validation, and if it fails, cancel the submit and display an error message in the view. And do not use the `RequiredAttribute` (sometime in the future someone might alter the code and add a constructor and then it will break). Create you own validation attribute (will only work server side) of just check `if (model.Surgeons == null || !model.Surgeons.Any())` and add a `ModelStateError`